# Origin http://localhost:8080 not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Tags: html, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I am running an html file on my localhost. I am accessing a php file on my server.

Javascript being run on localhost:

```
var url = "http://www.chartmygolf.com/_TEST_DELETE/exclude.php";
var method = "GET";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    // XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari.
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
} else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    // XDomainRequest for IE.
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
} else {
    // CORS not supported.
    xhr = null;
}

if (!xhr) {
    alert('CORS not supported');
    return;
}
// Response handlers.
xhr.onload = function (data) {
    var text = xhr.responseText;
    alert('Response: ' + text);
};
xhr.onerror = function (data) {
    alert('Woops, there was an error making the request.');
};
xhr.send();
```

The php on my server www.mysite.com:

```
<?php
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$parts = parse_url($referrer);
$domain = $parts['host'];
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://" . $domain);
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
$arr = array("181K2", "4V419");
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

In Chrome and Edge it goes into `alert('Woops, there was an error making the request.');`

Edge Error:

`SEC7120: Origin http://localhost:8080 not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.`
`SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80700013, Could not complete the operation due to error 80700013.`

Chrome Error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.chartmygolf.com/_TEST_DELETE/exclude.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.`

This is driving me insane. I have tried ajax and now this method and I get inconsistent results. I have read loads of threads here on stackoverflow and none of the answers work. (However, these threads seem to be ages old.)

Note: I get the same error if I use

`header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`

Please help. I am losing all grip on my sanity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. Found it. I do not have access to php settings on my server. It is a Windows server.

Putting this into a `web.config` file in the directory where the php script is does the trick.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If you are not on a windows server, you will need to do the `.htaccess` exquivalent of the above.